# Extracting non-null elements from a list of list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of list of data.frames called `G`.

**In BASE R**, I was wondering how I could *separately* extract elements `dint` and `SD` in `A` and `B` skipping any `NULL` elements?

**My desired output is:**  `dint = list(A = 1:3, B = c(1:4, 5:6) )
                        SD = list(A = 0:2, B = c(2:5, 3:4) )`

Here is the data:

```
G <- list(A = list(short = NULL, short2 = NULL, del1 = data.frame(dint = 1:3, SD = 0:2), 
               del11 = NULL), 
          B = list(short = data.frame(dint = 1:4, SD = 2:5), short2 = NULL, del1 = 
               data.frame(dint = 5:6, SD = 3:4), del11 = NULL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use nested `lapply`

```
lapply(G, function(x) unlist(lapply(x, `[[`, 'dint'), use.names = FALSE))

#$A
#[1] 1 2 3

#$B
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and similar for `"SD"` as well

```
lapply(G, function(x) unlist(lapply(x, `[[`, 'SD'), use.names = FALSE))

#$A
#[1] 0 1 2

#$B
#[1] 2 3 4 5 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just call a single `lapply` and extract the components

```
lapply(G, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)$dint)
#$A
#[1] 1 2 3

#$B
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Or to extract the 'SD'

```
lapply(G, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)$SD)  
#$A
#[1] 0 1 2

#$B
#[1] 2 3 4 5 3 4
```

---

It can be made into a function

```
f1 <- function(lstI, elementName){
            lapply(lstI, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)[[elementName]])
  }
f1(G, "dint")
f1(G, "SD")
```

---

`rbind` will get both the columns

```
lapply(G, function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

Comment: @Reza Then, you can wrap with `Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(G, ..`